# How do I specify nodeSelector while deploying an Azure ML model to an AKS Cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently deploying a model trained using AzureML to an AKS cluster as follows:

```
deployment_config_aks = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(
    cpu_cores = 1, 
    memory_gb = 1)

service = Model.deploy(ws, "test", [model], inference_config, deployment_config_aks, aks_target)
```

I would like this service to be scheduled on a specific nodepool. With normal Kubernetes deployment, I can specify a `nodeSelector` like:

```
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    myNodeName: alpha
```

How do I specify a `nodeSelector` while deploying an Azure ML model to an AKS Cluster? Or in general, is there a way to merge my custom pod spec with the one generated by Azure ML library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I specify a nodeSelector while deploying an Azure ML model to an AKS Cluster? Or in general, is there a way to merge my custom pod spec with the one generated by Azure ML library?

As per [Configure Kubernetes clusters for machine learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-attach-arc-kubernetes?tabs=studio):

`nodeSelector` : Set the node selector so the extension components and the training/inference workloads will only be deployed to the nodes with all specified selectors.

For example:

`nodeSelector.key=value` , `nodeSelector.node-purpose=worker` and `nodeSelector.node-region=eastus`

You can refer to [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#built-in-node-labels) and [Cannot create nodepool with node-restriction.kubernetes.io/ prefix label](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2866)